# Getting all search results from Github API

Tags: github, github-api

I was trying to search Github for all repositories that contains the word article in the readme.

I tried two methods:

1. API: https://api.github.com/search/repositories?q=article&in=readme.
2. Github Search box: https://github.com/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=article+in%3Areadme&type=Repositories&ref=searchresults

The first methods says there are total 9921 results, `"total_count": 9921,` whereas the search box finds 77638 repositories.

Why the discrepancy?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [advanced search page](https://github.com/search/advanced) shows that:

- `in:` is only for code search
- a general term is used for all searches (`-in:` is ignored for those searches, except for code search)

So:

- 9921 is the number of `readme` file with `article` in it
- 77638 is the number of repo including an `article` file, or arti`enter code here`cle in their titles.